# A good std::string cross-platform UTF8 alternative in C++11?

Tags: c++, string, wstring

I am trying to find a good alternative to `std::string` in games. `wstring` doesn't work properly in Android. So far I just use `ushort[]` with `0-65535` range(2 bytes per character) and it seems to work fine for 11 languages as bitmap fonts but moving forward I'd like to get a better implementation.

`u8"xxxyyy"` literal notations aren't supported in VC++ compiler yet, what other options do I have?

Comment: The path of least resistance is probably to just go ahead and put UTF-8 in `std::string` objects.  You will have to write UTF-8 literals using manually-encoded backslash escapes for anything not in the ASCII range, and you won't be able to use `locale`, but in my experience `locale` is useless anyway.

Comment: I am trying to get a correct UTF8 implementation so it's easier for others to modify the files for import.

Comment: Perhaps you should list thing things that are making you seek an alternative to UTF-8 `std::strings`s. If it's only that `u8` isn't supported in VS then you just need workarounds for that issue.

Comment: Why not keep the text in std:string or char[]?

Having the _content_ of the strings anywhere in the code is a clear road to nowhere.
Have your content/asset/resource system deliver them in binary/UTF8 format.

Everytime you find a xxx = "Game Over" in your code a game coder somewhere dies.

Comment: @Zack if you'd make that an answer and not a comment, I'd upvote it. It's the right way to go.

Comment: @moswald It feels like a non-answer to me, but eh, sure, why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of least resistance is probably to just go ahead and put UTF-8 in `std::string` objects. You will have to write UTF-8 literals using manually-encoded backslash escapes for anything not in the ASCII range, and you won't be able to use `locale`, but in my experience `locale` is useless anyway.  I can't personally vouch for its helpfulness, and it's inconveniently huge, but you *may* find that the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) libraries have routines geared to this strategy.

Comment: Not only is ICU helpful, it provides a dedicated type `icu::UnicodeString`, which can do all the fancy stuff you would expect of a Unicode-aware string class. However, in-memory storage is UTF-16, not UTF-8, so beware of memory consumption.